# Google Drive and Deletions

Tags: google-drive, account-management

I want to delete files from Google Drive (I've hit storage limit and don't want to buy more) **but STILL have those files on my PC** - I can't see a way to accomplish this and would appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 2):

Just move out those files of the Google Drive folder on your PC and place them on another folder.